# How to use multiple conditions in sql loader?

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I have one csv file with below format.First column is id second column is name and third column is dept. There are more than 700k rows in this file. I was trying to move only department 10, 90, 30 and 70 details in a oracle table by using SQL Loader.

```
100,AAA,10
101,BBB,10
102,CCC,20
103,DDD,30
104,EEE,40
105,FFF,50
106,GGG,70
107,HHH,60
108,III,20
109,JJJ,80
110,KKK,90
111,LLL,90
112,MMM,50
113,NNN,80
114,OOO,10
```

My table format is:-

```
create table DEPT_LOADER(
    ID NUMBER
    ,NAME VARCHAR2(100)
    ,DEPT number
);
```

and below is the control file

```
    load data
    infile 'F:\SQL_Loader\dept.csv'
    badfile 'F:\SQL_Loader\dept.bad'
    discardfile 'F:\SQL_Loader\dept.dsc'
    insert 
    into table DEPT_LOADER
    when dept = '10' or  dept = '90' or dept = '30' or  dept = '70'
    fields terminated by ','
    (id,name,dept)
```

but oracle didn't allow "or" operator in when clause. I tried with "in" clause and getting same type of error.

```
    SQL*Loader-350: Syntax error at line 7.
    Expecting "(", found "or".
    when dept = '10' or  dept = '90' or dept = '30' or  dept = '70'
```

Please help me on that. how can i use more than one condition in control file

Comment: I would rather filter out the file first before even passing it to sqlldr. It is wise to do so because the duty of sqlloader shud be to load the data into database as you give it and not to filter your file. Cleaning up should be done before even passing it. Looking at `F:`  it seems  you are doing it in Windows environment. In Unix, I would have used an awk command like `awk '$3 ~ /^(10|90|30|70)$/ {print} dept.csv >new_dept.csv`  to filter the records and then load `new_dept.csv`. Another option is to use **External Tables**, where you get *PREPROCESSOR*  option to do such manipulations.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Yes currently I am using Windows environment. can you please suggest how can i filter this large amount of data in windows environment? I never use External table. let my try with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL*Loader does not allow `OR` operator in `WHEN` clauses. You should use multiple `INSERT INTO DEPT_LOADER` .

Your control file should be like;

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'F:\SQL_Loader\dept.csv'
BADFILE 'F:\SQL_Loader\dept.bad'
DISCARDFILE 'F:\SQL_Loader\dept.dsc'
INSERT 
INTO TABLE DEPT_LOADER WHEN DEPT = '10'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
(
ID POSITION(1),
NAME,
DEPT
)
INTO TABLE DEPT_LOADER WHEN DEPT = '90'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
(
ID POSITION(1),
NAME,
DEPT
)
INTO TABLE DEPT_LOADER WHEN DEPT = '30'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
(
ID POSITION(1),
NAME,
DEPT
)
INTO TABLE DEPT_LOADER WHEN DEPT = '70'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
(
ID POSITION(1),
NAME,
DEPT
)
```

Comment: above script is only work for dept 10, other dept(90,30,70) are discarded.

Comment: I edited the post with POSITION(1) addition for each INSERT INTO statement. Please check whether this version works.

Comment: Yes it's working now.Thank you very much. Can you please explain me about position(1) or refer me any documentation. As per my knowledge position is used for fixed length flat file with proper position like col_name position(start_position : end_position).

Comment: It forces SQL*Loader to start loading from certain location in data. You can check the following reference for more information.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_control_file.htm#SUTIL1129